# How to work with two databases in utf-8 and iso-8859-1

Tags: php, database, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

i have a MySQL database that is working with UTF-8 encoding and a VisualFox database (dbase) that works with ISO-8859-1.

I'am having tons of issues with encodings.

I wonder if is better to work with my html pages on iso-8859-1 or utf-8. It's better convert iso to utf8 or utf8 to iso?

Or maybe, should i work with utf8 on the website when the data is from the mysql database and iso when i'm working with data from the visualfox database?  It's better mix or use only one codification.

I have a headache and thousand problems with the encoding, escaping, etc! Especially because of the lack of a good driver for odbc databases.

Finally, i wonder if i connect to mysql using iso-8859-1 codification i get the data in that codification instead of the utf8 that is stored the data?

Any tips?

Comment: You should use UTF8 everywhere.

Comment: ISO-8859 can only encode a fraction of the characters UTF-8 can. If you're using any non-"latin1" characters, you have virtually no choice but to use UTF-8. The trick is simply to keep everything in UTF-8 as much as possible. Convert data coming from the VF database asap and convert them to ISO-8859 as late as possible. That should be it, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UTF8 for flexibility.

Use the PHP [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) function to fix your data sync problems.

Comment: `utf8_encode` will not magically fix anything; that statement should be clarified a lot.

Comment: what? `utf8_encode()` is a very specific function that converts ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 encoding ... what does it not magically fix?

Comment: That's a necessary clarification for starters. You'll also have to go the other way when sending anything to the VF database.

Comment: realistically he should probably stick to UTF8 for evyerthing, but if he wants to go backward he can always use `utf8_decode()`. I advised against it though, because UTF is far more flexible. the only real advantage of ISO is the enterprise-level scalability, but if your application is pulling enough traffic to realistically be considering changing encodings to cut petty data-transfer costs, your application probably has a decent amount of international traffic as well. UTF8 across the board is probably his best option for a publicly accessible web app.

Comment: Sure. But I'll just assume he can't switch his VF database over to UTF-8 for whatever reason.

Comment: It's a enterprise website. The VisualFox database comes from a ERP Application where the company have all the data. The MysQL database is where i'm triying to work creating all the new stuff there. I'm having lots of issues, specially when data comes with \n\r or \r\n or \r or just '. If the number of ocurrences of the character ' is not even, the database throws an error and more strange errors like this one. So, if i try to insert this: "Brother's Data" it will throw  an error, instead, i must insert "Brother's Data'" with another '. The number must be even! strange. Thank you all

Comment: Escape the excess single quotes with `addSlashes()`